# ASP.NET 5 MVC6 - How to include the standard HTTP error views (404, 502, etc..)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I created a new empty Project in Visual Studio 2015 - Update 1 with ASP.NET 5, MVC6 and AngularJS. I want to see the standard error pages when there are errors like 404, 502 etc like shown in the example below.

[image]

How can I include those error messages?
At this time I can only look in my browser console and see the 404 errors.

The routing will be client side with the angular ui-router module (if this information is needed here).

Here you can see my startup.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace Chronicus
{
    public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {

            /*
            // auto generated code
            app.UseIISPlatformHandler();

            app.Run(async (context) =>
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
            });

            */
            app.UseIISPlatformHandler();
            app.UseDefaultFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            app.UseMvc();
        }

        // Entry point for the application.
        public static void Main(string[] args) => WebApplication.Run<Startup>(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I remember that content sent in such a status page needs to be more than I think 512 byte because otherwise IE replaces it with its own error message.

Comment: @Knacka - Isn't it already placed correctly in startup.cs?

Comment: It doesn't work either. Are there any additional steps to do?